# Is UBUNTU ready for the surge of (possible) new users?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, migration

With Windows XP Professional (SP3) coming to EOL. Is Ubuntu ready to welcome a surge of new windows users? The first thing people will want to know is, can they run their existing software on Ubuntu.

Strange how Ubuntu doesn't see the door of opportunity or maybe simply not concerned or simply doesn't have the desire.

Not a word on the home page.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: That concludes my sales pitch @alvar :D Oh, I am not an employee of Canonical. Just a user :-D

Answer (score 5):

> **Is UBUNTU ready for the surge of (possible) new users?**

We already are [20.000.000](http://www.canonical.com/partners) strong so Ubuntu is already ready. And we welcome any XP user!

[image]

But you need to improve your search skills ;-) Besides that the Ubuntu website is not the place to do this because IF anyone shows up there they already know about Ubuntu. Canonical is targeting larger crowds by *directly contacting* them and offering support and knowledge in setting up a transition from any operating system to Ubuntu.

Just 2 links from the Ubuntu websites ([more here](http://www.ubuntu.com/products/casestudies) and [here](http://www.canonical.com/about-canonical/resources/case-studies/)):

- http://www.ubuntu.com/products/casestudies/french-national-police-force-saves-2-million-year-ubuntu

> **French National Police Force saves €2 million a year with Ubuntu**
>
> La Gendarmerie Nationale upgrades 85,000 PCs to Ubuntu Desktop Edition
>
> La Gendarmerie Nationale’s IT team must ensure that the police force can provide a responsive and cost-effective service nationwide. With growing IT infrastructure costs, the organisation decided to review its existing Microsoft-based environment. After switching from Microsoft Office to OpenOffice.org and Internet Explorer to Firefox, the police force decided to upgrade 85,000 PCs to Ubuntu Desktop Edition, removing its reliance on the Microsoft operating system almost completely. As well as simplifying maintenance and improving ease of use, Ubuntu Desktop Edition is saving the police force €2 million a year in licence fees alone. By repurposing 4,500 machines to act as local servers, it has also dramatically reduced its hardware expenditure.

- http://www.canonical.com/about-canonical/resources/case-studies/andalusia-deploys-220000-ubuntu-desktops-schools-throughout-r

> The Andalusian Regional Government, Spain, wanted to improve access to IT in schools throughout the region. It asked IT services company infrastructure to connect 2,000 schools in Andalusia. Isotrol implemented 220,000 Ubuntu-based workstations in more than 2,000 schools throughout the region. Now, technology plays an integral role in delivering a more dynamic learning experience in schools across Andalusia. Teachers and students can share information quickly and easily, while each school receives dedicated support from a centralised support service.